# Tax calculation issue for a plugin

Tags: php, math, web, e-commerce

i am working on a plugin for prestashop, i am done with it, but i have stumbled on to an issue.

The program flow is as follows:

A person places an order at the eCommerce website, the order is accepted, the order details such as items, prices, taxes, discounts etc is send to an external invoice API service.

An example of an order could be:

(These prices include taxes)

1x T-shirt 20.64

1x Shipping 125

1x Discount -18.58 
(In this particular test case, the discount is 90% off the product, the math is simple 20.64 * 0.90 = 18.58)

Order total after tax is applied: **127.06**

This is all fine, but, when i send the details off to the API, the order is saved as the following:

(These prices are saved without tax applied, the tax rate being 25%)

1x T-shirt 16.51

1x Shipping 100

1x Discount -14

Order total after tax is applied: **128.14**

As you see, the order totals do not mach, the difference is 1.08, i am thinking this a discount & tax issue.

Its worth noting that the external site does its own math on the values sent, e.g products, tax etc. I cannot influence the way the external invoicing site does its calculations. I think the issue occurs in the order of which the operations are performed on the different platforms.

Its also worth mentioning that the code works perfectly fine when there is no discount present.

What can i do prior to sending the values, so that i get the prestashop price at the external service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the value of the items be `v_1` (t-shirt), `v_2` (shipping) untaxed values, respectively.

### Case 1.

1.25*`v_1`+1.25*`v_2`-0.9*1.25*`v_1` = **127.06**

### Case 2 (tax at end)

(`v_1`+`v_2`-0.9*`v_1`)*1.25 = Same as Case 1 after expanding the brackets.

The figure which is amiss is, as you suggest, the **-14** discount, which is more like **-0.9*16.51=-14.86**.

### 1.08 difference

There is a difference of 86 cents/pence, whatever, between the untaxed discount values. After taxes this difference grows to, 0.86*1.25=1.08, which explains the discrepancy.

To fix the code, the discount calculation needs to be fixed, unless there are other tax considerations that apply to discounts, etc. In other words why is -14 being used, rather than -14.86?

To you second point about the order of events, this should not impact anything - unless discounts are taxed differently.

### Fix

Either

- The discount calculation is wrong (i.e. 14 *should* be 14.86), or
- The discount value of 14 is *correct*, in which case a different (tax/discount) methodology than what is being assumed and this needs to be ascertained before you can make a fix for it.

Comment: Ty i will try to figure it ou